Can we assign different number of workers to different playwright test environments?
The application that I'm testing has single-user per session enforcement, so I've reduced the number of workers to 1. This has created the problem that my entire Playwright suite takes over an hour to complete.
However, about 2/3 of my tests run in our staging environment, and the remaining third run in production (I know, it's unavoidable). So my question is, would it be possible to increase my number of workers to 2, and assign one worker to staging and the other to production? In my mind, this would substantially speed up test runs, while avoiding the user overlap problem.
Here's my auth.setup.ts file:
import { test as setup, expect } from '@playwright/test';

const stagingFile = 'playwright/.auth/staging.json';

setup('authenticate in staging', async ({ page, context }) => {
  // Perform authentication steps
  await context.clearCookies();
  await page.goto(process.env.BASEURL!);
  await page.getByPlaceholder('Email').fill(process.env.USERNAME!);
  await page.getByPlaceholder('Password').fill(process.env.PASSWORD!);
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign in' }).click();
  await expect(page).not.toHaveURL(/sign_in/);
  // Wait until the page receives the cookies.
  //
  // Sometimes login flow sets cookies in the process of several redirects.
  // Wait for the final URL to ensure that the cookies are actually set.
  const orgs_url = process.env.BASEURL! + "/organizations"
  await page.waitForURL(orgs_url);

  // End of authentication steps.
  await page.context().storageState({ path: stagingFile });
});

const prodFile = 'playwright/.auth/prod.json';

setup('authenticate in prod', async ({ page }) => {
  // Perform authentication steps.
  await page.goto(process.env.PROD_URL!);
  await page.getByPlaceholder('Email').fill(process.env.USERNAME!);
  await page.getByPlaceholder('Password').fill(process.env.PASSWORD!);
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign in' }).click();
  await expect(page).not.toHaveURL(/sign_in/);
  // Wait until the page receives the cookies.
  //
  // Sometimes login flow sets cookies in the process of several redirects.
  // Wait for the final URL to ensure that the cookies are actually set.
  const orgs_url = process.env.PROD_URL! + "/organizations"
  await page.waitForURL(orgs_url);

  // End of authentication steps.
  await page.context().storageState({ path: prodFile });
});

Here's my project setup:
projects: [
    { name: 'setup', 
      testMatch: /.*\.setup\.ts/,
    },
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
      },
      dependencies: ['setup'],
    },

    {
      name: 'firefox',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Firefox'] },
      dependencies: ['setup'],
    },

    {
      name: 'webkit',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Safari'] },
      dependencies: ['setup'],
    },


Yes, you can assign different number of workers under different projects/environments.
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'P1',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
        baseURL: 'https://dev.example.com',
      },
      workers: 4, // Define the number of workers for this project
    },
    {
      name: 'P2',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
        baseURL: 'https://staging.example.com',
      },
      workers: 3, // Define the number of workers for this project
    },
    {
      name: 'P3',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Firefox'],
        baseURL: 'https://www.preprod.example.com',
      },
      workers: 2, // Define the number of workers for this project
    },
  ],


thank you for your answer! Do you know if it's possible to assign one worker to, say, 2 projects? E.g.: one worker for Projects A and B, one worker for Project C.
Total number of workers: 2

Yes, simply make two projects instead of 3.
